# Show table from a resultset into DBeaver (db oracle)

Tags: stored-procedures, resultset, oracle-xe, dbeaver

I need to know how to see the result of a query into a stored procedure.

A simple `select * from...` or any complex query just in the same way I see it after typing it from dbeaver SQL section.

The stored procedure is:

```
procedure TABLAS(oid in number, rec out stbienes%RowType)
As
Begin
   Select * into rec from stbienes    where oid_Art= oid;
End;
```

I'm using DBeaver 3.0.1 and Oracle XE.

Thank you very much.